# Compiling a standalone gtk#

Tags: compilation, mono, static-linking, gtk#

When I build my project, the resulting exe requires Gtk# in order to run. Are there any settings in MonoDevelop (or something) to statically link the Gtk# libraries in the compiled binary?

I'm developing on Windows 7 64bit, but I chose C# Gtk because I thought the code could be compiled for multiple OSs. However, I believe that a program as small as the one I'm working on should not force the user to install developer tools like Gtk.

Edit: I have found the [Embedding Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) webpage, but it looks like that deals with C code, GCC and Mono instead of C# code, Gtk# and MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best thing you can do is simply package gtk# with your application (it's a matter of copying a few dlls). However remember that gtk# is not a managed rewrite of gtk, it's just a set of wrapper libraries. As such, they need the native gtk to be present. You can of course ship that with your application too, but that enlarges your package by about 16MB. You can include the gtk installer or an already unpacked version that your end-users won't need to set up. Both solutions have merits.